# How to create rigth architecrture?

Tags: angular

I'm creating a chat component founded on WebSocket. Chat component has child components like ChatMessageList, ChatUserList, etc. So in this child components I have some duplicated code. Like:

(ChatMessageList)

```
        const APPROVED_ACTIONS = {
            'add.new.message' : 'addNewMessage'
        };    

        constructor(private chatService:ChatService) {
                chatService.messages
                    .filter((msg:WebSocketResponse):boolean => {
//check that recived action is approved
                        return APPROVED_ACTIONS.hasOwnProperty(msg.action);
                    })
                    .subscribe(
                        (msg:WebSocketResponse) => {
//Call the corresponding method
                            this[APPROVED_ACTIONS[msg.action]](msg);
                        }
                    );
            }

        addNewMessage(msg:WebSocketResponse) {
    ...
            }
```

(ChatUserListComponent)

```
 const APPROVED_ACTIONS = {
        'refresh.user.list' : 'refreshUserList'
    };    

constructor(private chatService:ChatService) {
    //like in ChatMessageList
}

refreshUserList(){...}
```

1 What patern is more usefull in angular for this case? Creating parent component, extend it and use super() in child constructor?

2 How i can configurate my components in order to removing APPROVED_ACTIONS  from constants? (Whould be nice if i can configure this in module, or in parent component by Injector)

3 This approach may not be applicable for angular at all?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i solve this case using components inheriting and made a configuration in a separate place:

ChatBaseChildComponent

```
export class ChatBaseChildComponent {
  constructor(protected chatService: ChatService) {
    chatService.messages
      .filter((msg: WebSocketResponse): boolean => {
        return CHAT_CONFIGURATION[this.constructor.name].actions.hasOwnProperty(msg.action);
      })
      .subscribe(
        (msg: WebSocketResponse) => {
          this[CHAT_CONFIGURATION[this.constructor.name].actions[msg.action]](msg);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

CHAT_CONFIGURATION:

```
export const CHAT_CONFIGURATION = {
  'ChatMessageListComponent': {
    actions: {
      'add.new.message': 'addNewMessage'
    }
  },
...
}
```

Use

```
export class ChatMessageListComponent extends ChatBaseChildComponent implements OnInit { ... }
```

But still not sure if this is a good solution...